# Why my QSqlDatabase::open() gets stuck?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I am trying to make a MySQL connection pool, in a way. The use case is this:

When i request a connection from it (QSqlDatabase object), it will generate a connection name based on the current thread id as a string. If I already have an open connection with that name, it'll return that one. Otherwise, it'll open a connection with that name, and it'll return it.

I also keep a flag which indicates if the connection is already in use and a timestamp of the last use. I also have a QTimer which ticks periodically and closes connections that aren't in use and haven't been used for some specified time.

I think the implementation is fine. However, every once in a while my getConnection() gets stuck. Here's a stack trace from gdb. When this happens, the program doesn't crash or anything like that, but getConnection() doesn't return.

```
#0  pthread_once () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/pthread_once.S:94
#1  0x00007f1fae288199 in get_charset_by_csname () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
#2  0x00007f1fae271a97 in mysql_init_character_set () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
#3  0x00007f1fae272960 in mysql_real_connect () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18
#4  0x00007f1fae77c0ad in ?? () from /usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
#5  0x00007f1fb5bd0251 in QSqlDatabase::open() () from /usr/local/Qt-5.2.0/lib/libQt5Sql.so.5
#6  0x00007f1fb895b479 in ConnectionPool::getConnection(QString const&) () from /home/user/demo1/lib/libMySqlConn.so
```

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
// Members of ConnectionPool:
// QMutex mMutex
// QHash<QString, ConnectionData> mConnections;

struct ConnectionData
{
    QSqlDatabase* pDatabase;
    QDateTime     lastUsed;
    int           refCount = 0;
};

QString ConnectionPool::getConnectionName()
{
    const quint64 tid = *reinterpret_cast<const quint64 *>(QThread::currentThreadId());
    return QString("%1").arg(tid, 12, 16, '0');
}

QSqlDatabase* ConnectionPool::getConnection(const QString& connName)
{
    QSqlDatabase* pDatabase = new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL", connName));
    pDatabase->setHostName("localhost");
    pDatabase->setPort(3306);
    pDatabase->setDatabaseName("test1");
    pDatabase->setUserName("user");
    pDatabase->setPassword("pass");
    pDatabase->setConnectOptions("MYSQL_OPT_RECONNECT=1");

    if (!pDatabase->open())
    {
        delete pDatabase;
        pDatabase = nullptr;
        QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(connName);
    }

    return pDatabase;
}

bool ConnectionPool::connection(QSqlDatabase& db)
{
    const QString connName = getConnectionName();
    QMutexLocker locker(&mMutex);

    if (mConnections.contains(connName))
    {
        ConnectionData& conndata = mConnections[connName];
        if (conndata.pDatabase->isOpen())
        {
            db = *conndata.pDatabase;
            conndata.refCount++;
            conndata.lastUsed = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
            return true;
        }
        delete conndata.pDatabase;
        mConnections.remove(connName);
        QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase(connName);
    }

    QSqlDatabase* pDatabase = getConnection(connName);

    if (!pDatabase)
        return false;

    ConnectionData conndata;
    conndata.refCount  = 1;
    conndata.pDatabase = pDatabase;
    conndata.lastUsed  = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
    mConnections.insert(connName, conndata);

    db = *pDatabase;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you please reformat the text heap into paragraphs with whitespaces in the middle? It is awkward to read like this.

Comment: thanks for the edit. Do you happen to be able to share some code?

Comment: I added a code snippet.

Comment: So, I call connection(), which in turn calls getConnection(), and that one gets stuck in the call pDatabase->open()